# Add IP to FACEBOOK WHITELIST not working

Tags: facebook, whitelist

Hello i am getting errors after i put in  the ip of my website,  but its saying  :

"Error

Your IP should be included in the Server-Whitelist.

Your IP should be included in the Update Settings IP Whitelist."

i  looked up the ip of my domain and put it in  the  app in facebook.still not accepting

Comment: How long have you waited? FB takes time to propagate that whitelist.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a programming question and answer site. It has a relationship with Facebook, but this is to help people with programming on Facebook's platform, not to provide support for Facebook in general. Please visit the official [Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help) instead. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/

It says you would put in the IP of the user that would update it's settings, not the website's IP address.

From my experience propagation of the app settings has been within seconds.